# if statement in python regex substitution

Tags: python, regex, perl, python-3.x

I have a regex that searches for `this` or `that`.  If it finds `this`, it replaces it with `ONE`.  If it finds `that`, it replaces it with `TWO`.

Here is what it looks like in Perl:

```
m =~ s/(this)|(that)/ "ONE" x!! $1 . "TWO" x!! $2 /eg
```

`e` is the *eval* option.  `.` is a concatenation.  `x!!` acts as an if statement.

How can I do the same thing in Python 3?  I'm looking for something like:

```
m = re.sub(r"(this)|(that)", ("ONE" * bool(match.group(1))) + ("TWO" * bool(match.group(2))), m, flags=re.EVAL)
```

I guess I have two main roadblocks.  Firstly, I don't know how to obtain the `match` object *within* a regex substitution.  Secondly, I don't know if eval is supported by python or what the best alternative is.

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python has no strange language syntax related to regular expressions - they are performed in well-behaved function calls.

So instead of a part of the call arguments that are executed on match, what you have is a callback function: all you have to do is to put a callable object as the second argument, instead of the substitution string. The callable receives the match object as its sole argument.

In this case, all you need is an inline `if` - so you can even define the callable as a lambda expression:

```
t = "this this that"
m = re.sub(r"(this)|(that)", lambda x: "ONE" if x.group() == "this" else "TWO", t   )
```

Comment: *"Python has no strange language syntax related to regular expressions"*. No, but is *does* have "strange language syntax" related to other things, and your tribalism isn't welcome

Comment: I tried to clarify your answer, but cannot make head nor tail of this: *"So instead of a part of the call arguments that are executed on match, what you have is a callback function: all you have to do is to put a callable object as the second argument, instead of the substitution string. The callable receives the match object as its sole argument"*. Please break it up and explain

Comment: *"so you can even define the callable as a lambda expression"* No *"strange language syntax"* here then! In Perl, a *lambda* is a subroutine without a name, and Python could be the same if `def` were more flexible